# Error in pom.xml while creating spring starter project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

Searches related to Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.bootcrud:crud:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.3.1.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter- parent:pom:2.3.1.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.3.1.RELEASE
 

com.bootcrud
crud
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
crud
Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a network issue `Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter- parent:pom:2.3.1.RELEASE `...just retry to build via `mvn -U clean package`...